# can't display vuejs data property inside vue template

Tags: vue.js, event-handling

I'm trying to use eventbus to send data from component A:

```
<template>  
        <div v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index" class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="card card-primary card-outline"> 
            <div class="card-body d-flex">
              <h1 class="mr-auto">{{ user.name }}</h1>
              <a href="#" @click="envoyerDetails(user)" class="btn btn-primary ml-auto">Afficher</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      users: {},
    }
  },
  methods: {
    envoyerDetails($data){
      Fire.$emit('envoyer_details_projet', $data);
      this.$router.push('details-projet');
    },
    loadUser() {
      if(this.$gate.isAdmin()){
        axios.get("api/user").then(({ data }) => (this.users = data.data));
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadUser()
  }  
}
</script>
```

In component B, i receive the data and i want to display it inside the template this way:

```
<template>
      <div class="right_col text-center" role="main">
        <h5><b>name: {{ user.name }}</b> </h5>          
      </div>
</template>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      user: {},
    }
  },
  methods: {
    afficherDetails (args) {
      this.user = args;
      console.log(this.user.name);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    Fire.$on('envoyer_details_projet', this.afficheDetails);
  }
}
```

The data is not displayed in the template but it is displayed in the console. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when you emit the event **envoyer_details_projet** in component A, but component B is not mounted yet so that it can't receive the data.

Comment: So I supposed to use vuex instead of using event bus

Comment: But why console.log display the data in component B ?